# How to reuse model validation outside of a controller?

Tags: c#, validation, model-view-controller

The specific functionality of MVC model validation that I want to leverage is validating data BEFORE it has been assigned to properties of an object instance.

For example if I have the class:

```
public class Test
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="Id is required")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Name is required")]
    [RegularExpression(Constants.SomeRegex,  ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid value for Name")]
    public int Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to validate that the value assigned to 'Id' can at least be assigned before trying to create an instance. In this case that would mean being assignable to an integer - so the value "ABC" would fail validation.

Of course I can't create an instance of Test with the value "ABC" for Id, it's not assignable to Int32.

MVC controllers implement this functionality - errors will be reported back before an instance of the model class can be created.

To this end, I have so far attempted using  System.CompondentModel.DataAnnotations.Validator

```
public bool IsValid(IDictionary<object, object> data, out OfferConfig offerConfig)
{
    offerConfig = new OfferConfig();

    var context = new ValidationContext(offerConfig, data);
    var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

    return Validator.TryValidateObject(offerConfig, context, results, true);
}
```

And passing in an instance implementing IDictionary

```
var dict = new Dictionary<object, object>
{
    {"Id", dataTable.Rows[i][0].ToString()},
    {"Name", dataTable.Rows[i][1].ToString()}
}
```

Like so:

```
Test testInstance;

bool isValid = IsValid(dict, out testInstance);
```

But maybe the Validator doesn't work as I'm expecting. Is the data argument supposed to be string object representations of the model properties? The validation results out appear as if values simply have not been assigned rather than being incorrect.

Hopefully someone can see what I'm trying to achieve here...

Comment: An alternative solution - make the property a string and write a custom validator to check that the string can be parsed to an integer. Then write another property that will return the value as an integer for use in the controller.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but I presume what I'm trying to do must be possible as MVC is doing it. If I can avoid creating a second class that would be better (the properties need to stay in the current data types for reasons I won't describe here)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - if a value won't bind to a property, the property will just assume its default value (unless the framework thinks it can bind it and fails, which is an exception scenario), beyond that (for real validation scenarios) the values *are* assigned to the model but `Model.IsValid` is false - the way to mirror this is with a string property and a custom validator.

Comment: So, in the example above, if I tried to submit a form to a controller action, and the value for id was 'abc', MVC would return a validation error saying that this was not a valid value, regardless of whether I had added any validation attributes. It's this behavior that I want to leverage outside of the controller.

Comment: The work around in your comment works, but it means I have had to create an additional class.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create new validation attribute in which you will place our validation logic. Like this:

```
public class StringIdLengthRangeAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public int Minimum { get; set; }
    public int Maximum { get; set; }

    public StringLengthRangeAttribute()
    {
       this.Minimum = 0;
       this.Maximum = int.MaxValue;
    }

    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        string strValue = value as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strValue))
        {
            int len = strValue.Length;
            return len >= this.Minimum && len <= this.Maximum;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is example validation of length - replace it with your validation logic.
And your class:

```
public class Test
{
   [Required]
   [StringIdLengthRange(Minimum = 10, Maximum = 20)]
   public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

With such attribute you are able to use that logic on any other fields.

Comment: Sorry this is not what I was asking.